# Add html element inside of form element using cake php form helper

Tags: php, html, cakephp, formhelper

I am trying to create a simple html output that looks like this

```
<button class="searchbutton" id="search_button" type="submit">-->
      <i class="icon-search"></i> Search</button>
```

with Cake php's form helper, i cant figure out why the 'after' attribute doesn't add the inner `<i> </i>` html element.

This is what i have tried.

```
  echo $this->Form->button('Search', array('type' => 'submit','id' => 'search_button','class' => 'searchbutton',
        'after' => "<i class='icon-search'></i>"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just include the extra `<i></i>` tag in the button `$title`, also include `'escape' => false` to ensure the mark up is not escaped, even though is not escaped by default as on v3.1.1, this may change in future, who knows..

Example:

```
echo $this->Form->button("<i class='icon-search'></i> Search", array('type' => 'submit','id' => 'search_button', 'class' => 'searchbutton', 'escape' => false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
echo $this->Form->button('Search', array('type' => 'submit','id' => 'search_button','class' => 'searchbutton','escape' => true,
        'after' => "<i class='icon-search'></i>"));
```

Comment: it is possible, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

see this

`echo $this->Form->button('Search', array('type' => 'submit','id' => 'search_button','class' => 'searchbutton','escape' => true,
        'after' => "<i class='icon-search'></i>"));`