# CakePHP - Best approach to add HTML content inside CakePHP form helper link?

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to add an icon inside the CakePHP form helper link generator code. I tried couple of options available on here on stackoverflow. But nothing seem to work.

This is my current code - I tried out this method [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016966/add-html-element-inside-of-form-element-using-cake-php-form-helper)

```
<?= $this->Html->link(('View'), ['action' => 'view', $group->id] , array('class' => 'dropdown-item' , 'between' => '<i class="la la-eye"></i>' , 'after' => '')) ?>
```

This method creates attributes inside the anchor tag. Which isn't what i'm trying to achieve.

I'm trying to achieve this.

```
<a href="groups/view/1" class="dropdown-item"><i class="la la-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
```

I'm using CakePHP 3.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", ["alt" => "Brownies"]),
    "recipes/view/6",
    ['escape' => false]
);
```

> Will output:

```
<a href="/recipes/view/6" title="hi &quot;howdy&quot;">
    <img src="/img/recipes/6.jpg" alt="Brownies" />
</a>
```

in your case:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    "<i class="la la-pencil"></i> Edit",
    "recipes/view/6",
    ['escape' => false]
);
```

Comment: Hi @salines Thank you for your help. Code works perfectly. Had to tweak a little bit. 
<?= $this->Html->link("<i class='la la-eye'></i> View", ['action' => 'view', $group->id], ['escape' => false, 'class' => 'dropdown-item']); ?>